# Keyboard randomly stops working on browser(Chrome), works again only when I type on the search bar of Applications Overview Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, lenovo

I have been facing this issue for a while now, where my keyboard stops working randomly on Chrome after [showing this sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jNcC.png):

[image: a white circle with a line through it, on a gray-black background]

I have tried waiting till the sign disappears, but nothing happends when I type on Chrome, or Firefox, or terminal (although, terminal opens by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Only when I go to search bar of Applications Overview and type something there, the keyboard comes back to life and works everywhere.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 330-15IKB (8gb RAM, 500GB SSD, Intel i5-7th gen, Nvidia 940MX graphics card).

I have tried looking if the memory usage is too much using `htop` command, but haven't found any significant difference. This used to happen once in a while, but has now happened 4 times in an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing the keystrokes using ScreenKey, I realized that some media keys were automatically pressed. Which resulted in the above issue. I am using an external keyboard currently, after disabling the laptop keyboard and have not faced this issue. This might suggest that there is no problem with the Ubuntu keyboard/touchpad drivers hopefully. It does seem a little obvious in retrospect but it was really hard to detect.